# how to custom sort a 2D javascript object?

Tags: javascript, sorting, javascript-objects

I started with this question: [How to sort a JS object of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286654/how-to-sort-a-js-object-of-objects)

From 2 of the comments I came up with my best way to sort a Javascript object of objects ( just a 2D object ).

Assuming the `data` is a 2D object variable, I sort by the `customer` value of the inner object.

First I convert to an array of objects, like this:

```
data = $.map(data, function(k, v) {
    return [k];
});
```

Then I do the sorting like this:

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.customer > b.customer? 1: -1;
});
```

It works well, but now I want to first sort by a date variable, then secondarily by the customer variable.  Just like the way the sorting functions work in SQL (`...sort by date desc, customer asc;`).

But, really what I want to do is actually much simpler. When sorting the date values, all I want to do is differentiate between `null` and `!null` values.  The result would be that all the null values would be grouped together, and all the not null values together.

After that, all the top-level objects should be in `customer` order.

I came up with this idea, based on how I think it should work:

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.fin_date !== null){
        return 1;
    }
    return a.customer > b.customer? 1: -1;
});
```

It is kind-of working.  It sorts all the `null` values to beginning, and all the null values are in correct alphabetical order, but all the other `fin_date` values (`!null1`) are not in alphabetical order.  They are not in order according to `fin_date` either.  The objects with `fin_date` not equal to `null` don't appear to be in any particular order.

So that is my problem: I need the objects with `fin-date` != `null` to be in alphabetical order.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean you're sorting an *array* of objects, right? Object properties aren't stored in any order.

Comment: Yes you're right, I updated my code above.

Answer (score 2):

You're not comparing the dates at all. Try something like this sorting function:

```
function(a, b) {
    var aDate = new Date(a.fin_date),
        bDate = new Date(b.fin_date);

    if (aDate < bDate) return -1;
    else if (aDate > bDate) return 1;

    return a.customer > b.customer ? 1: -1;
}
```

This assumes all your dates are later than 1970 (since `new Date(null)` is 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/TaSKZ/1/).