# How to sort an object of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I have an object of objects named teams:

```
{
"1": {
    "number": "134C",
    "robotName": "chazzen",
    "name": "Team Discovery - Charlie",
    "organization": "Pembroke Academy",
    "city": "Pembroke",
    "region": "New Hampshire",
    "country": "United States"
},
"2": {
    "number": "134G",
    "robotName": "Ghammer Time",
    "name": "Team discovery -Golf",
    "organization": "Pembroke Academy",
    "city": "Pembroke",
    "region": "New Hampshire",
    "country": "United States"
},
"3": {
    "number": "134K",
    "robotName": "Team Discovery kilo",
    "name": "Team Discovery -Kilo",
    "organization": "Pembroke Academy",
    "city": "Pembroke",
    "region": "New Hampshire",
    "country": "United States"
},
"4": {
    "number": "134E",
    "robotName": "Team Discovery -Echo",
    "name": "Team Discovery - Echo",
    "organization": "Pembroke Academy",
    "city": "Pembroke",
    "region": "New Hampshire",
    "country": "United States"
}
```

}

How do I sort these "sub-objects" alphabetically and numerically based on values such as "number" or "name" in a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a JS object of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286654/how-to-sort-a-js-object-of-objects)

Comment: You can’t. Object props don’t have an order. To order, use an array.